# Is it possible to add single full screen page of DirectX to a XAML/C# Windows 8 Store App?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, xaml, directx

I'm already aware of this
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/03/15/combining-xaml-and-directx.aspx

But I'm not clear if this is possible since the example is a single page game.

I want to construct a complete XAML/C# application with multiple XAML pages, used to deliver content.  But on one of the pages the user navigates to I want to render something using DirectX3D in the full screen.

Can I do this? If so can I build my full XAML/C# project and then just add a single page that uses SwapChainBackgroundPanel?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunately impossible at the moment with SwapchainBackgroundPanel, because your root visual element must be the SwapChainBackgroundPanel. (and add your other UIElements, frames, widgets etc. on top). You can achieve this with SurfaceImageSource, but at the cost of much more memory bandwidth (and most ARM based devices lack decent memory bandwidth).

Windows 8.1 leaked info and dumps of the 8.1 winmds seem to indicate that this is going to change soon however :).

Comment: One thing you can do, is to put a SwapchainBackgroundPanel as the root of your visual tree, and put your frame Inside it. So you have always a Direct3D surface available as a background. However, putting full screen xaml component on top of a SwapChainBackgroundPanel should be considered bad practice in term of performance, because then, Windows has to compose 2 full screen textures and that's really fillrate consuming especially on current gen ARM Windows RT devices.